# Permissions with Ubuntu booted on Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, permissions, multi-boot

I have Ubuntu dual-booted with macOS on a Mac. I'd like to access my Mac hard drive partition while on my Ubuntu account, but after trying to write to a file I get errors with permissions (but no errors for just reading). I changed the permissions of said file to read and write:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 502 dialout 26149 Sep 24 19:06 <name of file on Mac partition>
```

How do I get r/w/x access from my Mac files for Ubuntu? Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: You don't. And you shouldn't anyway. Whenever multi-booting and using shared files, those should reside in a data partition with a file system understandable by all the OSes involved. System partitions should not be accessed from outside the OS, let alone changing permissions.